# WPF bind ListView with dynamic columns count

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How to bind ListView if column count is not const? Here is a **Table class** which I need to bind:

```
public class Table
{
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public List<TableColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class TableColumn
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string ColumnType { get; set; }
        public List<Object> Values { get; set; }
     }
```

Example:

```
Table myTable = new MyTable();

TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn();
column1.Name ="MyColumn1";
column1.Values.Add("val1_col1");
column1.Values.Add("val2_col1");
column1.Values.Add("val3_col1");

TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn();
column2.Name ="MyColumn2";
column2.Values.Add("val1_col2");
column2.Values.Add("val2_col2");

myTable.Columns.Add(column1);
myTable.Columns.Add(column2);

//So, the ListView should be viewed like:
MyColumn1  MyColumn2
val1_col1  val1_col2
val2_col1  val2_col2
val3_col1  null
```

Comment: what is your question , can you please elabrorate more on this?+

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your data in a `System.Data.DataTable` and binding to that.